# SQL UPDATE all rows, except some rows, in table with composite primary key

Tags: sql, composite-key, except

I'm struggling with a SQL statement.

I want to update all rows except some, in a table with a composite primary key.

This is what I do now:

```
UPDATE Products SET Active = 0
```

_

```
UPDATE Products SET Active = 1
WHERE (Id_A = 1 AND Id_B = 1 AND Id_C = 1) OR
      (Id_A = 1 AND Id_B = 2 AND Id_C = 1) OR
      (Id_A = 5 AND Id_B = 8 AND Id_C = 3) OR
       .
       .
       .
       etc
```

This works, but I don't like it. I would like to be able to do it one go.

Is there some way to do this in SQL?

Comment: Why don't you put the rows that shouldn't be updated instead? What are the exceptions?

Comment: What database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... it would really help to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
UPDATE Products SET Active = CASE WHEN
      (Id_A = 1 AND Id_B = 1 AND Id_C = 1) OR
      (Id_A = 1 AND Id_B = 2 AND Id_C = 1) OR
      (Id_A = 5 AND Id_B = 8 AND Id_C = 3) OR
       .
       .
       .
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: I think he wants to reduce the number of restrictions and not putting them elsewhere.

Comment: Ah I was thinking he wanted 0/1 in a single update based on a condition

Comment: +1 then, but @JonList with your query you do it all in once as well, or are you making a lot of updates?

Comment: I do two updates (both queries from the initial post). I only know which products needs to be activate, so i deactivate everything in the db and then activate the ones i know needs to be active.

Answer (score 2):

In some SQL products, you can further simplify the syntax inside `CASE`, removing the multiple `AND` and `OR` to a simple `IN`:

```
UPDATE Products 
SET Active = CASE WHEN
      (Id_A, Id_B, Id_C) IN
      ( (1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 1), (5, 8, 3) ... ) 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 
             END ;
```

---

Another thing to consider is that if the table has a lot of rows (like millions or billions) and only a small percentage is set to `Active=1`, it will probably be more efficient to have the updating done is 2 statements, similar to what you had from the beginning, assuming you a have an index on `(Active)` (or a partial index on `(Active=1)` ):

```
UPDATE Products SET Active = 0 WHERE Active = 1 ;

UPDATE Products SET Active = 1 WHERE ... ;
```

Comment: unfortunately, my mssql does not like this one. I like the cleanness of it though

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a case expression inside an update statement?

Something like

```
UPDATE Products
    set Active = CASE WHEN (Id_A = 1 AND Id_B = 1 AND Id_C = 1) THEN 1 
                      WHEN (Id_A = 1 AND Id_B = 2 AND Id_C = 1) THEN 1                         
                      .
                      .
                      . 
                      ELSE 0 END
```